# std::transform with lambda: skip some items

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda

I have some C++11 code like

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::map<std::string, std::string> first_to_last_name_map;
std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::inserter(first_to_last_name_map, first_to_last_name_map.begin()), [](const std::string& i){
    if (i == "bad")
        return std::pair<std::string, std::string>("bad", "bad"); // Don't Want This
    else
        return std::pair<std::string, std::string>(i.substr(0,5), i.substr(5,5));
});
```

where I'm transforming a vector to a map using std::transform with a lambda function.  My problem is that sometimes, as shown, I don't want to return anything from my lambda function, i.e. I basically want to skip that `i` and go to the next one (without adding anything to the map).

Is there any way to achieve what I'm thinking about?  I can use boost if it helps.  I want to avoid a solution where I have to do a pre-process or post-process on my vector to filter out the "bad" items; I should only need to look at each item once.  Also, my actual logic is a bit more complicated than the if/else as written, so I think it would be nice to keep things encapsulated in this std::transform/lambda model if possible (though maybe what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible with this model).

EDIT: Just to emphasize, I'm looking to perform this operation (selectively processing vector elements and inserting them into a map) in the most efficient way possible, even if it means a less elegant solution or a big rewrite.  I could even use a different map data type depending on what is most efficient.

Comment: personally, I'd write a `transform_if` template function--it would mirror the naming scheme of other algorithms like `copy_if` and keep the resulting code simple and comprehensible.

Comment: Half a decade late comment but a simple for each loop and inserting the elements in the map didn't work for you?

Comment: @Zoso I don't have the code in front of me now, but one could imagine: I store a lambda somewhere that various parts of my code use for doing this type of processing/filtering (maybe I even have a collection of lambdas for different filters etc.).  So in that case I'm stuck using lambdas; and I want my lambdas to do the processing, not just return true/false whether the processing should be done.  And if the logic for checking badness of an item is very complicated, I want that logic buried inside the lambda (not repeated). So transform_if + lambda may be cleaner than foreach + badness checks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class Src, class Sink, class F>
void transform_if(Src&& src, Sink&& sink, F&& f){
  for(auto&& x:std::forward<Src>(src))
    if(auto&& e=f(decltype(x)(x)))
      *sink++ = *decltype(e)(e);
}
```

Now simply get a boost or std or std experiental optional.  Have your `f` return an `optional<blah>`.

```
auto sink = std::inserter(first_to_last_name_map, first_to_last_name_map.begin());
using pair_type = decltype(first_to_last_name_map)::value_type;

transform_if(names, sink,
  [](const std::string& i)->std::optional<pair_type>{
    if (i == "bad")
      return {}; // Don't Want This
    else
      return std::make_pair(i.substr(0,5), i.substr(5,5));
  }
);
```

My personal preferred optional actually has begin end defined.  And we get this algorithm:

```
template<class Src, class Sink, class F>
void polymap(Src&& src, Sink&& sink, F&& f){
  for(auto&& x:std::forward<Src>(src))
    for(auto&& e:f(decltype(x)(x)))
      *sink++ = decltype(e)(e);
}
```

which now lets the `f` return a range, where optional is a model of a zero or one element range.

Comment: I like this answer as well, but does it also require looking at each item in the vector twice, once inside the lambda and then again inside the if in transform_if (or implicitly inside the range iterator for f in polymap)?  I am hoping to consider each element in the vector only once.

Comment: @davewy What do you mean by "consider" or "looking"?  The `if` clause branches on the engageness of the optional (is it empty or not), not on the contents of the optional.  It moves the contents out of the optional into the sink, which also isn't "looking".  And the "looking" is done one element at a time -- there is only one pass here.  So, I am not sure what you are saying.

Comment: I mean that there are two comparison operations performed for each element: the first comparison `(i == "bad")` determines what value the optional should have, and then the second `if` looks at whether the optional has a value or not.  So two comparisons are performed before inserting the element into the map.  I want to perform only one comparison with or operation on each element in the vector before inserting the valid ones into the map.

Comment: @davewy So, your problem is you have a lambda which returns the equivalent of `false`, then the code calling the lambda does an `if`, and you are worried about that because ... performance?  Or some other reason?  First, it is in code that is about to *allocate memory* (maps are node-based), which is going to be 10x more expensive than even a failed branch.  Second, the second branch is quite removable by a compiler that inlines the lambda, and that is what lambdas are for (ease of inlining).  Finally, even if not inlined, it is highly predictable, and branch prediction makes it free.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply have a first/last pass with `std::remove_if`.  E.g.

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::map<std::string, std::string> first_to_last_name_map;
std::transform(names.begin(), 
               std::remove_if(names.begin(),
                              names.end(),
                              [](const std::string &str){
                                    return str=="bad";
                              }),
               std::inserter(first_to_last_name_map, 
                             first_to_last_name_map.begin()),
               [](const std::string& i){
                     return std::pair<std::string, std::string>(i.substr(0,5), i.substr(5,5));
               });
```

Note that `remove_if` simply shifts the removed items past the iterator it returns.

Comment: This would work, but does this require 2 passes through the vector, one to construct the iterator returned by remove_if and one to do the transform?  I'm hoping to do something like this but to visit each item in the vector just once.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`boost::adaptors::filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) to first filter the `vector` of the elements you don't want, before passing it to `transform`.

```
using boost::adaptors::filtered;
boost::transform(names | filtered([](std::string const& s) { return s != "bad"; }),
                 std::inserter(first_to_last_name_map, first_to_last_name_map.begin()),
                 [](std::string const& i) { return std::make_pair(i.substr(0,5), i.substr(5,5)); });
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f11c36f78a13d4e2)

Comment: This would work, but does this require looking at each element in the vector twice, once to perform the filter and then again inside the lambda?  I'm hoping to do something like this but to visit each item in the vector just once.

Comment: @davewy The Boost adaptors are lazy. Here's a demo - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60c28e85ec08bbe3. For some reason, the lambda is called once for the very first element in the `vector` before the call to `transform` (maybe that's just how the range composition works) but other than that, the `vector` is being traversed within the call to `transform`.

Comment: Thanks!  In the code sample you provide, it looks like elements are printed out two or three times.  Even though boost adaptors are lazy, they still require evaluation when the iterator visits an element.  So each element is visited two or three times, not just once.  Any ideas?

Comment: @davewy Here's the same example made less noisy - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fadee6ebf30cd7c6. I'd defined the `string` conversion operator to avoid defining the other operators for `MyString`, but since I defined them anyway, that conversion is not necessary. So each element is being printed twice, once for the filtering and once for the transform, not sure how you want to avoid either.